# MVC Client Side Validation in NodeJs, ExpressJs, Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

How can i achieve model based client side validation in NodeJs, ExpressJs and mongoose. Similar to MVC4 validations in .Net

Can anyone suggest a node module or code or a link.

Please refer to below link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718004/ASP-NET-MVC-Client-Side-Validation

Thanks in advance.

Comment: good question, I would like a good answer also